# Google maps javascript won't style buildings outside US

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I used this google maps javascript options to style maps

```
var Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(canvasID), {
        center: {
            lat: 58.913528,
            lng: 25.670033
        },
        zoom: 14,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        rotateControl: true,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                stylers: [
                    {visibility: "off"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#242f3e"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#746855"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#242f3e"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#d59563"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#ff7c17"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#d59563"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#263c3f"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "poi.park",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#6b9a76"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#38414e"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#212a37"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#9ca5b3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#746855"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#1f2835"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#f3d19c"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#2f3948"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "transit.station",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#d59563"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#17263c"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#515c6d"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#17263c"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

In styled maps google maps don't style `landscape.man_made` outside US cities.
Screenshot of random place in Kansas City,US.
[image]

If i navigate my self to random place in Tallinn,Estonia.
Then buildings are no more outlined. [image]

In this google maps night mode example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling buildings are not outline at all.

Comment: Interesting, probably, Google doesn't have a building information in all countries world-wide. A would suggest reach out to Google Maps Platform support team to figure it out.

Comment: However [Google Maps shows building outlines](https://www.google.com/maps/place/A.+Adamsoni+%26+Koidu,+10137+Tallinn,+Estonia/@59.4330245,24.7287986,18z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x46929484a75993e1:0xdf56e1930b779d8c!8m2!3d59.4328977!4d24.7294692)

Comment: The default view has building information, yes maybe its best to contact support